# Date format issue about simpleFormatDate

Tags: java, solr

```
    Timestamp tsmp = Timestamp.valueOf("0302-02-20 00:00:00");

    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    System.out.println(df.format(tsmp));
```

this code segment prints : `0302-02-20 12:00:00`

why is that?

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of output you are expecting but I assume you wonder why it prints `0302-02-20 12:00:00` instead of `0302-02-20 00:00:00` . That is because you are using `hh` pattern to format hour. That prints hour in am/pm format. You could either use it with am/pm marker `a` or format in 24 hour with `HH`.

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
```

would print `0302-02-20 12:00:00 am`.

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

would print `0302-02-20 00:00:00`.

More info about the patterns are here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html